# app engine NeedIndexError: no matching index found

Tags: python, google-app-engine

trying to deploy the simple guestbook 
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstartedpython27/deploying-the-application

I got an error trying to deploy the app like so :

```
appcfg.py --verbose -A glossy-apex-130310 -V v1 update ./
07:56 PM Application: glossy-apex-130310 (was: None); version: v1 (was: None)
07:56 PM Host: appengine.google.com
2016-05-06 19:56:11,019 INFO sdk_update_checker.py:229 Checking for updates to the SDK.
2016-05-06 19:56:11,607 INFO appcfg.py:2378 Reading app configuration.
07:56 PM
Starting update of app: glossy-apex-130310, version: v1
07:56 PM Getting current resource limits.
2016-05-06 19:56:11,608 INFO appcfg.py:1693 Send: /api/appversion/getresourcelimits, params={'version': 'v1', 'app_id': 'glossy-apex-130310'}
2016-05-06 19:56:12,350 ERROR appcfg.py:2396 An error occurred processing file '': HTTP Error 403: Forbidden Unexpected HTTP status 403. Aborting.
Error 403: --- begin server output ---
You do not have permission to modify this app (app_id=u's~glossy-apex-130310').
--- end server output ---
```

So I deployed it like so :

```
gcloud preview app deploy --project glossy-apex-130310
```

http://glossy-apex-130310.appspot.com/
getting this 
    Internal Server Error

```
The server has either erred or is incapable of performing the requested operation.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 1535, in __call__
    rv = self.handle_exception(request, response, e)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 1529, in __call__
    rv = self.router.dispatch(request, response)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 1278, in default_dispatcher
    return route.handler_adapter(request, response)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 1102, in __call__
    return handler.dispatch()
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 572, in dispatch
    return self.handle_exception(e, self.app.debug)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/webapp2-2.5.2/webapp2.py", line 570, in dispatch
    return method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/base/data/home/apps/s~glossy-apex-130310/20160506t132909.392595029440587911/guestbook.py", line 72, in get
    greetings = greetings_query.fetch(10)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/ndb/utils.py", line 160, in positional_wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwds)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/ndb/query.py", line 1203, in fetch
    return self.fetch_async(limit, **q_options).get_result()
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/ndb/tasklets.py", line 378, in get_result
    self.check_success()
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/ndb/tasklets.py", line 422, in _help_tasklet_along
    value = gen.throw(exc.__class__, exc, tb)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/ndb/query.py", line 980, in _run_to_list
    batch = yield rpc
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/ext/ndb/tasklets.py", line 508, in _on_rpc_completion
    result = rpc.get_result()
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/api/apiproxy_stub_map.py", line 613, in get_result
    return self.__get_result_hook(self)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/datastore/datastore_query.py", line 2921, in __query_result_hook
    yaml_index=yaml, xml_index=xml)
NeedIndexError: no matching index found. recommended index is:
- kind: Greeting
  ancestor: yes
  properties:
  - name: date
    direction: desc

The suggested index for this query is:
- kind: Greeting
  ancestor: yes
  properties:
  - name: date
    direction: desc
```

`index.yaml` file is

```
indexes:
- kind: Greeting
  ancestor: yes
  properties:
  - name: date
    direction: desc
```

I read that I'm supposed to wait a while. it's been 4 hours.

There are No indexes created here
https://console.cloud.google.com/datastore/indexes?project=glossy-apex-130310

Comment: Can you see the status of that index at https://console.cloud.google.com/datastore/indexes?project=glossy-apex-130310 ?

Comment: hi @snakecharmerb added in the question. no indexes exists there

Comment: I'm guessing it was supposed to auto generate but wasn't . where are relevant logs that I can view to debug this?

Comment: The index-building process isn't exposed by Google.  I'd guess the `app deploy` command doesn't deploy indexes.  Try the `create indexes` command at https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/preview/datastore/create-indexes

Comment: You might also want to take a look at https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadinganapp#uploading_an_app to see if you can work out why your original upload failed - I'd guess that the oauth setup didn't happen.  If you can get it working, `appcfg.py` uploads both code and indexes.

Comment: worked!. thanks. you can add it as an answer and i'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The gcloud sdk can upload indexes to the Cloud Datastore with the `create-indexes` command, like this ([docs](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/preview/datastore/create-indexes)):

`$ gcloud preview datastore create-indexes ~/myapp/index.yaml`

The App Engine SDK will upload indexes along with application code when `appcfg.py` is executed with the [update command](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadinganapp#uploading_an_app):

`$ appcfg.py -A <YOUR_PROJECT_ID> update myapp/`

or indexes can be uploaded separately when `appcfg.py` is executed with the [update_indexes command](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadinganapp#updating_indexes):

`appcfg.py update_indexes myapp/`